# Comparing numeric dates Best12 vs DATE9

Tags: sas

I have two tables with numeric dates that I want to compare but am having trouble because they are in different formats.

One is format Best12, informat 12 and the other is Date9.

Because they are both numeric, the syntax is valid, but I don't get any matches.  How can I convert these into the same numeric format?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to compare the values.  Ideally, along with some sample data. The formats should not effect the comparison, the stored values should be compared, regardless of the formats attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date in numeric format is likely something of the form YYYYMMDD and isn't a SAS date. Change it into a SAS date and your comparison will be valid.

Or change the SAS date to a numeric form above and do the comparison, but I recommend the first option.

Answer (score -1):

Use a format statement.

```
data test2;
    set test;
    format var1 var2 date9.;
run;
```